# When is Scala 2.8.0 going to be released?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, release-cycle

Or a release candidate? My google-fu fails me.

Comment: Scala 2.8.0 was released today: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7009

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a little out of date, but gives a rough idea:

http://www.nabble.com/Re%3A-Any-guesstimated-release-dates-for-2.8-final--p24919161.html

Based on my experience with the nightlies, and porting some code to 2.8, I would add about 2 months to those estimates. You can get a feel for the activity here:

https: // lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/timeline

2.8 is a **big** release, including:

- unnested packages
- new collections library

  - hashCode() of mutable collections now throws Unhashable
- new arrays
- named/default params

  - case classes generate copy() methods
- @specialised
- fixed equality / hash code handling across primitives and boxed primitives
- RichString replaced by WrappedString

  - so that "abc".reverse.reverse == "abc"
- ability to control annotation targeting (i.e. field, getter or setter; class or constructor)
- support for nested annotations
- delimited continuations compiler plugin
- better compiler support for the Eclipse Scala Plugin
- refactored actors implementation
- refactored pattern matcher implementation
- tweaked rules for implicits
- many other bug fixes...

Which is to say that it is likely to take a few release candidates to reach the elusive 2.8.0 status.

Comment: Update Jan 18 2010: The beta release is imminent, so I was about a month or two short with my guess. But it will be worth the wait!

Answer (score 3):

Ask the Scala mailing list, Grasshopper.

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/199

Comment: In particular, you can browse scala-internals here <http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals>. All the release candidates are announced there.

Answer (score 3):

2.8.0 Beta 1 Release Candidate 4 was just released. They're getting there!

Answer (score 2):

That's because no firm dates have been set.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any release date has been set. 2.8 is a big release though, so don't hold your breath.

In the mean time, you can get a [nightly build](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/212/distributions). I've been using the nightlies for several months, and they work pretty well. Before downloading a nightly though, make sure you check the [Hudson server](http://scala-webapps.epfl.ch/hudson/) to make sure the build actually succeeded.